# check if my variable is not integer in "if" statement in c++

Tags: c++, if-statement

I have written c++ code and this is part of it:

```
int flag8=1,
     tmp,
     part;
      .
      .
      .
 if(part > 7 || !(int)tmp || tmp < 0){
      cout << "ERROR !!!\n";
      flag8=0;
      break;
    }
```

how can I check my tmp variable is integer or not?

I want to say my if statement be true if `part>7 or tmp is not integer or tmp<0`.
thank you very much.

edit:
this is my whole code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int base2toten(int nums);
int base8toten(int num);

////////////////////////////////////////////
/*   FUNCTION: CONVERTING BASE 2 TO 10   */
////////////////////////////////////////////
int base2to10(int nums){
int base2,
    digits,
    base10=0,
    parts,
  powers=1,
  flag2=1;

  cout << "Enter num base 2: ";
  cin >> base2;
  //if(!(int)base2 && base2 < 0 || !(int)base2 && base2 > 1){
  // cout << "OUT OF RANGE"    
  //}

  digits = base2;

  while(digits){ 
    parts = digits % 10;

    if(parts > 1 || !(int)base2 || base2 < 0){
      cout << "The number you have entered is not base 2 !!!\n";
      flag2=0;
      break;
    }

    digits /= 10;
    base10 += powers * parts;
    powers *= 2;    
}

  if(flag2){
    cout << " \"base2\":\t" << base2  << "\n" 
     << "\"base10\":\t" << base10 << endl;
  }
}


///////////////////////////////////////////
/*   FUNCTION: CONVERTING BASE 8 TO 10   */
///////////////////////////////////////////
int base8to10(int num){
  int base8,
    digit,
    base10=0,
    part,
    power=1,
    flag8=1;

  cout << "Enter num base 8: ";
  cin >> base8;

  digit = base8;

  while(digit){
    part = digit % 10;
    if(part > 7 || !(int)(base8) || base8 < 0){
      cout << "The number you have entered is not base 8 !!!\n";
      flag8=0;
      break;
    }

    digit /= 10;
    base10 += power * part;
    power *= 8;
  }
  if(flag8){
    cout << "\"base8\":\t"   << base8  << "\n" 
     << "\"base10\":\t"  << base10 << endl;
  }
}


//////////////////////////////////////////
/*           FUNCTION: MAIN             */
//////////////////////////////////////////
int main(){
  int num,nums,a ,b,ans;

  //  cout << "What base you want to convert?\n"
  cout << "*******************************************************\n"
       << "*            BASE TWO:                2               *\n"
       << "*            BASE EIGHT:              8               *\n"
       << "*            BOTH BASE TWO AND EIGHT: 28              *\n"
       << "*            BOTH BASE EIGHT AND TWO: 82              *\n"
       << "*******************************************************\n";

  cout << "What base you want to convert? ";
  cin >> ans;

  if(ans != 2 && ans != 8 && ans != 28 && ans !=82){
    cout << "Your answer in not acceptable!!!\n";
  }

  else if(ans == 2){
    cout << "**********************************\n"
         << "*     YOU'VE CHOSEN BASE 2       *\n"
         << "**********************************\n";
    base2to10(a);  
  }

  else if(ans == 8){
    cout << "**********************************\n"
     << "*     YOU'VE CHOSEN BASE 8       *\n"
     << "**********************************\n";
    base8to10(b);
  }

  else if(ans == 28){
    cout << "*********************************************\n"
     << "*     YOU'VE CHOSEN BOTH BASE 2 AND 8       *\n"
     << "*********************************************\n";
    base2to10(a);
    base8to10(b);
  }

  else if(ans == 82){
    cout << "*********************************************\n"
     << "*     YOU'VE CHOSEN BOTH BASE 8 AND 2       *\n"
     << "*********************************************\n";
    base8to10(b);
    base2to10(a);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: you declared tmp as int, so it is `int`.

Comment: How could it be a non-integer? It's declared as `int`.

Comment: just think someone enter float number in input part...I want reject him

Comment: c++ is a strongly typed language, hence the comments above.  You could cast it as something else, but underneath its still 32bits (assuming 32 bit integers)

Comment: Can you include the code in question where someone put in a float number?

Comment: Then you need to validate the data type at the point of input and reject it if it's not an integer.

Comment: How about taking a string input and parsing it?

Comment: here is the whole code...someone enter a float number rather than base8...I want to reject him

Comment: @pinkpanther good idea...can you show me how?

Comment: Use `getchar()` until the person enters `newline` if at any point of time person enters a `.` then it means it's a floating point number...

Comment: very good idea...can you put piece of code as you said? thank you very much

Comment: I am new with c++ ... how good some guys are..they all gave me negative point

Comment: @MortezaLSC _'they all gave me negative point '_ Yes, that's because your question asks for an XY problem, and isn't very well suited for being a good question on SO. See my answer; after reading through the comments, I think I have figured out what you want to achieve.

Comment: @MortezaLSC I wrote the code in the answer..check it up.........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question very likely asks for an [XY-Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Since C++ is a typed language, the type you have used to declare a variable will always stay the same.

You'll need to check the state of your input stream, to test if the input was given in the correct format:

```
int tmp;

std::cin >> tmp;
if(!cin)
{
    // user input was not parsable as integer value ...
}
```

If you want to specify particular numeric input formats, you can use stream manipulators (need to [`#include <iomanip>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip)):

```
std::cin >> std::oct >> tmp; // Will parse integer from base 8 input
std::cin >> std::hex >> tmp; // Will parse integer from base 16 input
```

Comment: I said in whole code digit = base8 ...so your solution doesn't work :(

Comment: @ῥεῖ any idea?I think this is possible by adding sth to your help

Comment: @MortezaLSC You want to have input of octal numbers, do I understand you right? I'll update my answer ...

Comment: @MortezaLSC As a hint: To parse input from base 2 input, you can use an intermediary `std::bitset` variable (which supports conversion from `std::string`).

Comment: thank you very much..I didn't get answer in my code...but I think I can use your solution in these cases

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of what you want...Hope this helps...

**This is only an example and you may have to check thoroughly and modify before using it in a real world app..**

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    int n=0;
    char c;
    do{
        c=getchar();
        if(c>='0' && c<='9'){
            n=n*10;
            n+=(c-48);
        }
        else if(c=='\n'){
            break;
        }
        else{
            printf("SOME THING  WRONG");
            break;
        }
    }while(1);
    printf("%d ",n);
    return 0;
}
```

Since you are saying base8 (from 0 to 7) modify the if statement with `if(c>='0' && c<='7')`

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I did it just to give an intuition...any ways i will modify it

Comment: _'I did it just to give an intuition'_ Bad one, there are much better and shorter solutions in C++ ...

Comment: Please use character literals instead of their decimal values, such as '0' instead of 48.  Makes the code easier to read.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews thank you very helpful tip indeed...will edit